# Explain recursive function for finding max element in array

Tags: recursion

I decided to incorporate recursions into my code and for that I want to train using it. I have a recursive function which finds the max element in the given array.

```
def maxx(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    else:
        m = maxx(lst[1:])
        return m if m > lst[0] else lst[0]

maxx([1,3,2])
> 3
```

I tried to draw a sequence of events and I can't get why the code above works?
Because according to what I see it should be **2** not **3**. Where is my mistake? Is there a method that correctly expands the recursion and thus helps you to understand its flow?

[image]

Comment: Check in your notes the content of the array in each recursion. When you get back the 2 from the last return, you compare it with `array[0]`, which is 3 so you return 3, then you go up again and `array[0]` is 1 so 3 goes out again. P.S. It's confusing to read that you expect the code to throw out a 2 looking for max value :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth 0:

```
lst = [1,3,2]
m = maxx([3,2])
```

Depth 1:

```
lst = [3,2]
m = maxx([2])
```

Depth 2:

```
lst = [2]
returning 2
```

Back to Depth 1:

```
lst = [3,2]
m = 2
return m (2) if m > lst[0] (3) else return lst[0] (3)
returning 3
```

Back to Depth 0:

```
lst = [1,3,2]
m = 3
return m (3) if m > lst[0] (1) else return lst[0] (1)
returning 3
```

The reply by Alfabravo is correct, I think that's where you lost track of lst[0] as you went back up the tree.